# Deduplicating/collapsing records in an R dataframe

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe, na

I have a dataset that is comprised of various individuals, where each individual has a unique id. Each individual can appear multiple times in the dataset, but it's my understanding that besides differing in one or two variables (there are about 80 for each individual) the values should be the same for each entry for the same user id in the dataset.

I want to try to collapse the data if I can. My main obstacle is certain null values that I need to back populate. I'm looking for a function that can accomplish deduplication looking something like this:

```
# Build sample dataset
df1 = data.frame(id=rep(1:6,2)                 
                ,classA=rep(c('a','b'),6)
                ,classB=rep(c(1001:1006),2)
                )
df1= df1[order(df1$id),]
df1$classC=c('a',NA,'b',NA,NA,NA,'e','d', NA, 'f', NA, NA)
df1[10,"classB"]=NA
df1=df1[df1$id!=6,]

#sample dataset
> df1
   id classA classB classC
1   1      a   1001      a
7   1      a   1001   <NA>
2   2      b   1002      b
8   2      b   1002   <NA>
3   3      a   1003   <NA>
9   3      a   1003   <NA>
4   4      b   1004      e
10  4      b   1004      d
5   5      a   1005   <NA>
11  5      a     NA      f        

# what I'm looking for
> deduplicate(df1, on='id')
  id classA classB classC
1  1      a   1001      a
2  2      b   1002      b
3  3      a   1003   <NA>
4  4      b   1004      d
5  4      b   1004      e
6  5      a   1005      f
```

Comment: Because I messed up my data example when I added the case for id=5 :p. Fixed

Comment: maybe you should consider marking some of your questions as answered (if they did answer)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? (solution using `data.table`)

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df1)
# ignore the warning here...
unique(DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = id])

   id classA classB classC
1:  1      a   1001      a
2:  2      b   1002      b
3:  3      a   1003     NA
4:  4      b   1004      e
5:  4      b   1004      d
6:  5      a   1005      f
```

Some explanation:

- the `by = id` part splits/groups your data.table `DT` by `id`.
- `.SD` is a read-only variable that automatically picks up each split/group for each `id` one at a time.
- we therefore split `DT` by `id`, and to each split part, use `lapply` (to take each column) and remove all `NA`s. Now, if you've let's say `a, NA`, then, the `NA` gets removed and it returns `a`. But the input was of length 2 (`a, NA`). So, it automatically *recycles* `a` to fit the size (=2). So, essentially we replace all NA's with some already existing value. When both are `NA` (like `NA, NA`), `NA`s are returned (again through recycling).
- If you look at this part `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = id]`, you should be able to understand what has been done. Every `NA` will have been replaced. So, all we need to do is pick-up `unique` rows. And that's why it's wrapped with `unique`.

Hope this helps. You'll have to experiment a bit to understand better. I suggest starting here: `DT[, print(.SD), by=id]`

---

#### Final solution:

I just realised that the above solution will not work if you've got, for example, for `id=4` another row with `classC = NA` (and everything else is the same). This happens due to *recycling* issue. This code should fix it.

```
unique(DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- x[!is.na(x)][1]; x}), by = id])
```

Comment: This definitely looks like what I want, but I only recently startd learning about the data.table package. Can you maybe walk me through what this is doing a little so I'm not just blindly using someone else's code? This definitely looks great, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I haven't been able to succesfully use this to dedupe my full dataset yet, but I think that's a property of my variables and the data cleanliness. Your solution definitely satisfies the requirement I set with the sample data (and further intrigued me about the data.table package) so I'm marking as solved. Thanks for the help! I'll definitely be holding onto this snippet for future data-munging.

Comment: If you were here I'd kiss you. Wrapped this in a function that loops over each variable deduping it against ID to figure out which variables are unique in my ID variable... like butter, and super fast on a 10000x80 subset of my data.

Comment: hmmm, just to be sure, if you're interested, post an example where this solution as such fails and I'll look into it to see what's wrong. PS: I think you used the **final solution**?

Comment: I don't think I articulated my problem clearly: the problem wasn't that your solution was failing me per se, so much as there were certain variables in my dataset that had unique non-null values for each row. These variables can be ignored. And yes, I did use your "final solution."

Answer (score 1):

I would, first check whether there are row duplicated **id** and with **missing classC** and remove them like this :

```
dd <- df1[duplicated(df1[,1]) & is.na(df1$classC), ]
df1[setdiff(rownames(df1), rownames(dd)), ]
  id classA classB classC
1  1      a   1001      a
2  2      b   1002      b
3  3      a   1003   <NA>
4  4      b   1004      e
8  4      b   1004      d
```

**EDIT**

I think to generalize the above for many columns , one idea is to put your data in the long format using `melt` for example:

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m  <- melt(df1,id.vars='id')
dd <- dat.m[order(dat.m$id),]
rr <- dd[duplicated(dd$id) & is.na(dd$value),]
kk <- dd[setdiff(rownames(dd), rownames(rr)), ]
kk <- kk[!duplicated(kk),]
dcast(kk,id~variable,drop=FALSE,fun.aggregate=list,fill=list(NA))
  id classA classB classC
1  1      a   1001      a
2  2      b   1002      b
3  3      a   1003     NA
4  4      b   1004   e, d
5  5      a   1005      f
```

The final result is slightly different from your desired output, but you can get it with a little work (strsplit for example).

Comment: Not a bad start, but I've got about 80 columns in my data: can you generalize this to work with multiple columns that might have NA values in them? Also, this wouldn't satisfy the case (which I didn't show in my example data) where the first entry has var1 populated and var2 null, and the second entry has var1 null and var2 populated.

Comment: @DavidMarx I edit my answer for many columns. I didn't get  your point about var1,var2,...Maybe can you add a data example.

Comment: Updated my question with id=5 to illustrate the case I was trying to describe. Basically, I'm not operating under the assumption that the nulls are all in one record. One record might have nulls that need to be populated by a different record, and that other record might have nulls that need to be populated by the first record.