# compress rows with NA in different columns to create a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a data frame like this

```
test <- data.frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:2],each = 3), 
    a = c(1,NA,NA,10,NA,NA), 
    b = c(2,NA,NA,20,NA,NA), 
    c = c(NA,3,NA,NA,30,NA), 
    d = c(NA,NA,4,NA,NA,40))
```

I got this dataframe, and want to convert it so there only one row for each unique 'id' and no NAs in the dataframe.

I am doing this

```
ddply(test, 
    .variables = 'id', 
    .fun = function(df){
        colSums(df[,1:4], na.rm = T)})
```

to get this data.frame

```
      id  a  b  c  d
    1  A  1  2  3  4
    2  B 10 20 30 40
```

It works, but is there a more direct way of doing it without using `colSums`, sort of compress the rows to create a single row for each 'id', because within each 'id', all columns have only one value and the rest are NAs. I did come across a similar request somewhere while looking for something else but cannot find it now!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266578/deduplicating-collapsing-records-in-an-r-dataframe

Comment: another way: `split(na.omit(unlist(test[, -1], use.names=FALSE)), c(FALSE, TRUE))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using R base functions

```
> test[is.na(test)] <-0
> aggregate(.~id, data=test, FUN="sum")
  id  a  b  c  d
1  A  1  2  3  4
2  B 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: @Jilber Thanky for the suggestion. As my data.frame is too big the melt-cast technique fills up my RAM followed by my swap, only to restart again. May be base-R is the way to go in this case!. My reputation does not allow me to upvote it, but I would have like to. Thx again

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that was recommended to me when I had a similar problem, using data.table and is.na:

```
require(data.table)
DT=data.table(test)

unique(DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = id])

   id  a  b  c  d
1:  A  1  2  3  4
2:  B 10 20 30 40
```

Note that this gives you a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`. If you're not comfortable working with this data structure, you can easily convert it:

```
data.frame(unique(DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = id]))

  id  a  b  c  d
1  A  1  2  3  4
2  B 10 20 30 40
```

via: [Deduplicating/collapsing records in an R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266578/deduplicating-collapsing-records-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you. it certainly is the same question. I will remember that 'collapsing records' rather than 'compress rows'

Comment: Note: `x[!is.na(x)]` is equivalent to `na.omit(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is a whole lot easier, but:

```
test <- data.frame(id.l = rep(LETTERS[1:2],each = 3), 
                   a = c(1,NA,NA,10,NA,NA), 
                   b = c(2,NA,NA,20,NA,NA), 
                   c = c(NA,3,NA,NA,30,NA), 
                   d = c(NA,NA,4,NA,NA,40))
x <- melt(test, id.l = id, na.rm = T)
dcast(x, id.l ~ variable)
# id.l  a  b  c  d
# 1    A  1  2  3  4
# 2    B 10 20 30 40
```

I had to change the name of your id column since I couldn't make `id = id`.

Comment: Thank you. I use plyr and reshape so much, just did not occur to try them out here! :( And yes, probably 'id' is not a safe variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` solution is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(a = na.omit(a)[1], b = na.omit(b)[1],
c = na.omit(c)[1], d = na.omit(d)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `base`

```
apply(test, 2, function(x) unique(na.omit(x)))
```