R remove excess duplicates that are encompassed in another row
I have an 'index' dataset that I would like to reduce. I would like to reduce rows that are identical but have NAs compared to another. However, I do not want to remove rows if one has information in one column that the other does not. For example:



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
B
D
G
NA


A
B
NA
NA
NA


A
B
NA
NA
H


NA
NA
D
G
NA


NA
NA
NA
NA
H



Would reduce to



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
B
D
G
NA


A
B
NA
NA
H



Because Row 2 and Row 4 are weaker duplicates of Row 1 they are removed. Row 3 is different to Row 1 as it has H, so contains information I want to keep and is not a duplicate of Row 1. Row 5 is a duplicate of Row 3, do that is removed too.
I have many columns i'd like to apply it to, so not using "group_by", I believe. Any coding suggestions?
I have considered dplyr, group_by, na.omit and duplicates, but can't find the right one
Rcode:
data= data.frame(col1=c("A", "A", "A", NA, NA),
                 col2=c("B", "B", "B", NA, NA),
                 col3=c("D", NA, NA, "D", NA),
                 col4=c("G", NA, NA, "G", NA),
                 col5=c(NA, NA, "H", NA,"H"))

EDIT: Original answer that I thought was correct was not, as it removed rows that were unique if some of their entries were repeated (see comments below).

Thank you, Andre. I have since found this method (Final solution), do you think it will work in my case if I do not use "by="?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266578/deduplicating-collapsing-records-in-an-r-dataframe

That won't work either. The tricky part is you want to treat NA's as any character that have appeared in lagging rows per column. Thats why you want row 3 of your original example to appear. If no NAs are present in a row its rather easy, we can simply test the pasted characters against all other and filter with duplicated.

Indeed! I tried to think if there was a way to fill in the NAs based on the other rows (like a look-up) which would fill in the NAs to match the superior lines, and then only take one of each duplicate, but I've not found a way to do that either.

Doesn't work for my dataset, as the integrity of the rows needs to be maintained. So for the example I gave it's important for ABDG to be separate to ABH, but the above merges them.

Unfortunately no cigar, my data is not ordered. For a counterexample:
data <- structure(list(col1 = c("I", "A", "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A",
"A", "A", "A"), col2 = c("J", "B", "B", NA, NA, "B", "B", "B",
"C", "C", "C"), col3 = c("K", NA, NA, "D", NA, "D", "E", "F",
"D", "E", "F"), col4 = c("G", NA, NA, "G", NA, "G", "G", "G",
"G", "G", "G"), col5 = c(NA, NA, "H", NA, "H", "H", "H", "H",
"H", "H", "H")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

In your example row 3 can fit in row 8 so should be removed. In my example row 4 is not removed either.

This might even work with unsorted data, give it a try data[data %>% fill(everything(), .direction="down") %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(grp = paste(c_across(everything()), collapse="")) %>% ungroup() %>% reframe(grp = case_when(cur_group_id() == 1 & row_number() == 1 ~ T, cur_group_id() != 1 & row_number() == n() ~ T, T ~ F), .by = grp) %>% unlist(),]

Does this do the job?
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  structure(
    list(
      col1 = c("I", "A", "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
      col2 = c("J", "B", "B", NA, NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
      col3 = c("K", NA, NA, "D", NA, "D", "E", "F", "D", "E", "F"),
      col4 = c("G", NA, NA, "G", NA, "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"),
      col5 = c(NA, NA, "H", NA, "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -11L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

# Row pairings
pairs <- crossing(V1 = 1:nrow(df), V2 = 1:nrow(df)) |> filter(V1 != V2)

# Match pairings
discard <- pmap(pairs, \(V1, V2) {
  tibble(
    V1,
    V2,
    compare = df[V1, ] |> 
      add_row(df[V2, ]) |> 
      fill(everything()) |> 
      summarise(across(everything(), n_distinct)) |> 
      sum()
  )
}) |>
  bind_rows() |>
  filter(compare == ncol(df)) |>
  pull(V2)

# Discard "weaker duplicate" rows
df |> filter(!row_number() %in% discard)
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1    I    J    K    G <NA>
#> 2    A    B    D    G    H
#> 3    A    B    E    G    H
#> 4    A    B    F    G    H
#> 5    A    C    D    G    H
#> 6    A    C    E    G    H
#> 7    A    C    F    G    H

Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0
